# Using bfill with a chosen number

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame column like so:

```
 Year   Rank
  2017    Nan
  2017   Nan
  2017    3
  2017    4
  2017    5
      .
      .
  2016    Nan
  2016    Nan
  2016    3
  2016    4
  2016    5
     .
     .
```

Can I use bfill to replace the first two value so my column looks like this...

```
  Year   Rank
  2017    1
  2017    2
  2017    3
  2017    4
  2017    5
      .
      .
  2016    1
  2016    2
  2016    3
  2016    4
  2016    5
     .
     .
```

Or is there an easier way than using bfill? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameter `limit` in [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['Rank'] = df['Rank'].fillna(1, limit=1)
df['Rank'] = df['Rank'].fillna(2, limit=2)
```

...and if necessary call function per groups:

```
def f(x):
    x = x.fillna(1, limit=1)
    x = x.fillna(2, limit=2)   
    return x

df['New'] = df.groupby('Year')['Rank'].apply(f)
print (df)
   Year  Rank   New
0  2017   NaN   1.0
1  2017   NaN   2.0
2  2017   3.0   3.0
3  2017   4.0   4.0
4  2017   5.0   5.0
5  2016   NaN   1.0
6  2016   NaN   2.0
7  2016   5.0   5.0
8  2016   6.0   6.0
9  2016  10.0  10.0
```